# How Can I Add BeautifulSoup Results To A Dictonairy in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I want to put all the results of a BeautifulSoup request in a dictionary in Python and have the key to all of them be "https". My current code looks like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml").find_all("td", class_="new");
for soup in soup:
    info = {};
    info["https"] = soup.text;
```

But if I run it and do `print(len(info))` it only returns one when `soup.text` returns much more.

Comment: Can you share the source upon which you’re basing your claim that you can have multiple entries in a dictionary (or any competent/practically useful key/value data structure) with the same key? How would you plan on referencing them as such…?

Answer (score 1):

You're generating a new dictionary every iteration, and you'd be overwriting the same key every time. If what you want is to have a list of all the entries at the same key, you can do it like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml").find_all("td", class_="new")
info = {"https": [soup_.text for soup_ in soup]}
```

Though you might not need the dictionary then. You can't have multiple entries with the same key.